# Karate - Testing different environments - with or without API Gateway

Tags: karate

I am using two different environments to test - Dev env is without authentication (so we don't have to pass headers) and QA env is hosted on API Gateway. I was trying to design my tests such that the tests should be configurable to run in either of the environments.

Here is what I have done:

1. Defining Client Secret and Client Id in the Karate-config.js. Setting these two variables as null for dev.
2. Calling a user-login scenario file to generate the authorization token (takes url, client_id and client_secret from the scenario file) and return token to the scenario file.

   Feature: Test using Karate

   ```
     Background:
       * configure ssl = true
       * url baseUrl
       * def token = call read('classpath:endpoints/user-login.feature')
       * def headerData = {Authorization: #(token.nextGen),Accept: 'application/json;v=1'}
       * headers headerData

     Scenario: Verify that status for retreiving endpoint
       Given path 'abc'
       When method get
       Then status 200
   ```

   Feature: Get Token

   ```
   Scenario: Get authorization header
     Given url 'https://api-it.cloud.xyz.com/oauth2/token?client_id=12121&client_secret=12121&grant_type=client_credentials'
     When method get
     Then status 200
     And def tokenType = response.token_type
     And def accessToken = response.access_token
     * def nextGen = tokenType + ' '+ accessToken
     * print nextGen
   ```

Any pointers on how to run tests with and without authentication on the same project will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this section of the doc: https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic

Note that `eval` is from 0.7.0 onwards, but you can easily use a JS function, have an `if` condition within in and do what you need - by making a `karate.call()` from the JS function to set headers (or not).

Comment: Thans @Peter Thomas, that's helpful.